# using MVA attributes in Sphinx

Tags: php, mysql, search, sphinx

Suppose we have three tables:

1. pr_brand (id,title)
2. pr_brand_usages (id,pr_brand_id,pr_usages_id)
3. pr_usages (id,title)

The query in `sphinx.conf` file is:

```
SELECT p.id,p.title as title
FROM pr_brand p
LEFT JOIN pr_brand_usages u ON u.pr_brand_id = u.id

sql_attr_string = title
sql_attr_multi = uint pr_usages_ids from query; SELECT id,title from pr_usages
```

I get pr_usages_ids=0  (nothing) When I run my query in console:

my query:

```
select * from my_index;
```

We have a facet with multi selection ([this page](http://product.statnano.com/search)).
Can you help me to solve this problem?

[image]

UPDATED:

I changed the query in `sphinx.conf` file :

```
SELECT p.id,p.title as title
FROM pr_brand p
```

<strike>LEFT JOIN pr_brand_usages u ON u.pr_brand_id = u.id</strike>

```
sql_attr_string = title
sql_attr_multi = uint pr_usages_ids from query; SELECT pr_brand_id,pr_brand_usages_id from pr_brand_usages
```

<strike>sql_attr_multi = uint pr_usages_ids from query; SELECT id,title from</strike>

Is it correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Your 'edit' looks ok for the MVAs.

(But your `sql_attr_string` will mean the title will become a attribute, leaving your index with no fields. The index will be non-functional. Maybe use `sql_field_string` if do want a string attribute (it makes a field AND a attribute)

Comment: Yes you're right. but how can I get title field ( pr_usages )?